# C - Can't Create/Write to Files in VS2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, text-files, visual-studio-2017

**Question Edited**
i'm giving a bit of a background on my problem hoping that'll help you understand it better:

I've recently updated my IDE to VC++ 2017 . I've written a basic assembler (for mips ISA) as part of my studies.

All worked well till i've reached the final part of printing the memory image to text file - i've noticed that altough the file pointer was allocated with a value(not NULL) after using "fopen", nothing was written to it. 
Here is the definition and the opening of the input/output files(out of context since lack of space);

```
//File Pointers
FILE *fp_mem = NULL, *fp_asm = NULL;
/** Entering Main Function **/

// open files
fp_asm = fopen(argv[2], "r");
fp_mem = fopen(argv[1], "w");

if (fp_asm == NULL || fp_mem == NULL)
{
    perror("ERROR");
    exit(errno);
}

/** Assembler functionality **/
//write to file loop
for (i = 0; i <= highest_mem_access && i < MEM_SIZE; i++)
{
    int temp = fprintf(fp_mem, "%08X\n", mem[i]);
}
//free label memory
free_label_list();
fclose(fp_asm);
fclose(fp_mem);
```

I tried various options instead of `fpritnf` - didn't work.

**Most importantly - No File is created in my project directory!**

Any idea guys? i'm pretty hopeless... I'll share more of my code if needed.

**EDIT** 
This is a simple try to write to files in VS2015:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //FILE *fp = fopen("C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/test.txt", "w");
    FILE *fp = fopen("test", "w");

    if (fp == 0)
    {
        perror("ERR");
        return(11);
    }

    int count = fprintf(fp,"Hello there,General Kenobi");

    fclose(fp);
}
```

fp isn't NULL , Count = 26 after fprintf , No file located anywhere.
I also tried to write to another location(in comment) - same issue.

Comment: Thanks , i've just edited my question - the exception was due to a 'w' instead of "w" parameter in the fopen() function. syntax mistake. However, i'm still can't create "write-enable" files in my original program.

Comment: Still, check your CWD - with getcwd or _getcwd (where program is started and what is its current working directory). Try fputs with some debug string to check that file output is working. Try to make MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - small program which demonstrates the error, and post full source (sometimes fprintf may not work in MSVC if intl header is included)

Comment: I've checked - File output isn't working at all . Zero chars are written by fputs or fprintf. I can't find an CWD equivelent for windows run-time - do you know any? Anyway, i'm working on building MVCE . it's a bit complicated since technically the error related lines are only two . **Also , i can read from files perfectly ok**